# Is it possible to determine the minimum width of an HTML5 div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a short content like this

```
<div id="reginald">
    <span style="whitespace: no-wrap">Wrap me if you can!</span>
</div>
```

How can I find out what the mininum width of this div would be?

Comment: Wouldn't the minimum width depend on font size?

Comment: Just using `min-width` CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:  You temporarily set its parent's width as small as possible, and then measure it!

```
// Shrink the parent.
var oldParentWidth = $("#reginald").css("width");
$("#reginald").css("width", "1px");

// Measure the child.
var width = $("#reginald span").width();

// Put it back.
$("#reginald").css("width", oldParentWidth);

console.log(width);
```

Also, you probably mean `white-space: nowrap`, since the content, as written, does actually wrap.

**Update:**  Here's a fiddle demonstrating it:  https://jsfiddle.net/seanofw/2nakzqjf/

Answer (score 0):

The minimum width of the div depends on two factors, one being the content in it, ie. the length of the text, its font-size etc., which makes it hard to determine the minimum width of the div as the content can change but you can still do

```
var width = $("#reginald").width();
```

The other factor is the CSS property min-width set in the stylesheet which can be obtained as

```
var minWidth = $("#reginald").css("min-width");
```